# R randomForest crash with oob.prox=FALSE

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm consistently able to crash R with this lines:

```
    library(randomForest)

    x = matrix(runif(400), nrow=20)
    y = runif(20)

    rf = randomForest(x, y, proximity=TRUE, oob.prox=FALSE)
```

with oob.prox=TRUE it runs fine.

Can you reproduce this?

Thanks,
Immanuel

```
    > sessionInfo()
    R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
    Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

    locale:
    [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
    [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
    [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
    [10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

    other attached packages:
    [1] randomForest_4.6-7

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] tools_2.15.1
```

Comment: R does not crash but inform me about an access violation. So it seems to be a problem for me too. This being said, this is off-topic here (it's a specific package and software issue) and should be taken to the package maintainer.

Comment: Thanks, I'm informing the package maintainer right away. I'm sorry for being off-topic, I was suspecting an error on my side.

Comment: For future reference, any segfault is a bug by definition and if you can reliably reproduce it (even if it ends up being specific to your setup) do not pass go, do not collect $200, go directly to the package maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

The bug should be fixed now in the version on R-forge ("4.6-8").  Should be on CRAN eventually.

Problems with packages are best communicated to the package maintainer directly.  Some do not read this site regularly.  I would not have known about this if no one brought it to my attention via email.